# trim and converting text to general format with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have stuck with below macro in which I need to trim and convert the adjacent column data which is in text format, I need it in general format.

My data is J column I'm trimming it on K column copy pasting it as special values on column J. Also assuming data to be within 5000 rows. would be great if someone can help me with getting it trim and general pasted in J till the last row of the data. below is the code i am using with. Thanks.

```
Sub TrimPS()
Range("K2").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))"
ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=1
Range("K5000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.Copy
Range("J2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,  SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("K2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("K2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: Firstly It is taking 5000 rows but I want it as per data in column J and when i'm trying to paste it in general format in column J it is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TrimPS()
    Dim rngLast As Range

    Set rngLast = Range("J1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp)

    With Range("J2", rngLast)
        .Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))"
        .Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    End With

    Set rngLast = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jim.. that's what I wanted.. I am aligning same with different columns too..